# Jade won't render html form

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Jade won't render the view.
If I change the contents of the new.jade file to a paragraph it renders fine. So I don't understand what is happening.
If I look at the console there is a 500 error

Thanks in advance

Here is some more details

the new.jade file

```
h1 Log in

form(method="POST", action="/session")
  p
    label(for="username") Username<br />
    input#username(name="username")
  p
    label(for="password") Name<br />
    input#name(name="name")
  p
    label(for="password") Password<br />
    input#password(type="password", name="password")
  p
    label(for="bio") Bio<br />
    textarea#bio(name="bio")
  p
    input(type="submit", value="Create");
```

the app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var sessions = require('./routes/session')

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser('my secret string'));

app.use(session({
    secret: 'my secret string',
    maxAge: 3600000,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/session', sessions);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Lastly the session.js which calls it

```
var express = require('express')
var session = require('express-session')
var router = express.Router();

var users = require('../data/users');

var app = express();

router.get('/new', function(req, res) {
    res.render('session/new', {title: "Log in"});
    //res.send("testing");
});

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("test")
})

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    if (users[req.body.username] &&
        users[req.body.username].password === req.body.password) {
        req.session.user = users[req.body.username];
        res.redirect('users');
    } else {
        res.redirect('session/new')
    }
});

router.delete('/', function(req, res) {
    req.session.destroy();
    res.redirect('users');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm just baffled

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `;` at the end of your jade file.

Comment: change `input(type="submit", value="Create");` to `input(type="submit", value="Create")`

Comment: That doesn't actually seem to make a difference. Paste the OP's code into http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/

Comment: Maybe the OP should remove it and see if it works then?

Comment: Thank you very much mvuajua. removing the ; at the end fixed it. cheers